# A hook to add support for thmtool's notefont in ntheorem

Tags: theorems, thmtools, ntheorem, patching

I want to use `ntheorem` extended with `thmtools`. In the documentation of the latter, I read:

> **notefont** (Value: TEX code). Executed just before the note in the head is typeset, inside a group. Intended use
> it to put font switches here. Formatting also applies to the braces around the note. **Not supported by ntheorem.**

I wonder whether it is possible to add a hook to some internal `ntheorem` command to add support for this. Naively, I think of something like:

```
\patchcmd{\some@command}{(##3)}{{\thm@notefont (##3)}}{}{}
```

but I can't figure out what command to patch when I read the commented `ntheorem.sty` in the docs.  Is something like this possible?

Comment: I know, I could manually redefine all the theorem styles, but this isn't really a satisfactory solution.